# Display a special file depending on the network with ansible

Tags: networking, ansible, ansible-facts

I need help. I want to deploy some files with some modifications. The deployment policy is that depending on the network the server belongs to, it will deploy some files or others.

My idea is to create a .yml (Defining the networks) with the name of the networks.  (vars_file)

For example:

Work:
192.168.2.XXX
send file type A

Office:
192.168.3.XXX

My main idea was to use the conditions in Ansible.

When the server has an interface that belongs to 192.168.2.XXX it sends a text file for example.

When it belongs to 192.168.3.XXX it sends an audio file

File vars:

```
---

vlan:
- networkname: Work
  netname: 192.168.3.0
  netmask: 255.255.255.0
  netface: "{{vars.ansible_facts[ansible_interfaces]}}"
```

Playbook

```
- name: Test move
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
   - vlan.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Copy
      copy:
         src:  "/tmp/file.mp3"
         dest: "/opt/tmp/file.mp3"
      when: 
        - (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item]|default({})).get('ipv4', {}).get('address') = {{item.netname}}
      with_items:
        - "{{vlan.netface}}"
```

First failed:

```
"FAILED! => {"msg": "dict object has no element [u'lo', u'ens192', u'ens160']"}"
```

Comment: That all sounds reasonable. What have you tried so far? We're not going to write playbooks for you, but we are happy to help if you try something and it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Sorry! I wrote the quick post. I've already updated the ticket. As I have modifications I will post them

Answer (score 0):

Several problems in your above example.

The current error you get is linked to your vlan.yml declaration. The following line will fire an error every time it is interpreted causing your entire `vlan` var to be undefined anyway.

```
netface: "{{vars.ansible_facts[ansible_interfaces]}}"
```

1. `ansible_interfaces` is the key (as a string) where you are using its value.
2. You don't need to lookup that fact, it is already available to you directly

You can fix with the following:

```
netface: "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
```

Now, your `vlan` var is finally defined

Your next problem is that `vlan` is a list, thus `vlan.netface` does not exists... but `vlan[0].netface` does. If you want to loop on each interface of each vlan, the easiest way here is to use a [subelements loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements).

The following (not tested) should put you on the right track

```
    - name: Copy
      copy:
         src:  "/tmp/file.mp3"
         dest: "/opt/tmp/file.mp3"
      when: 
        - (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item.1]|default({})).get('ipv4', {}).get('address') = {{item.0.netname}}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vlan }}"
        - netface
```

You may have other problems to fix in your when clause that I could not test at this point.

Comment: I'm trying to make a condition with the facts but it makes me a skipe when the values are really right:


    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"

Vars:


> item.0.interface -> "{{ ansible_interfaces }}" item.0.network ->
> "192.168.3.0"



Conditional

> when:    item.0.network in ((hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s'
> % item.0.interface]|default({}))   
> .get('ipv4'))|map(attribute='network')|list

¿can you help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and add that code formatted correctly with all the needed info to explain what your are trying to do, what is the actual result and the expected one.

Comment: I just posted the commentary, I hope it's understood

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the condition to work.

I've modified the get "addres" through the "network"

> (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' %
>   item.1]|default({})).get('ipv4', {}).get('address') =
>   {{item.0.netname}}
>
> (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' %
>   item.1]|default({})).get('ipv4', {}).get('network') =
>   {{item.0.netname}}

The error message is:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check
>   '(hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item.1]|default({}))
>   .get('ipv4', {}).get('network') = {{item.0.netname}}' failed. The
>   error was: Invalid conditional detected: invalid syntax (,
>   line 1)\n\nThe error appears to be in 'test.yml': line 8, column 6,
>   but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n   - name:
>   Copy\n     ^ here\n"}

Playbook:

```
  tasks:
   - name: Copy
     copy:
      src: "/tmp/file.mp3"
      dest: "/opt/tmp/file.mp3"
     when:
      (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item.1]|default({}))
       .get('ipv4', {}).get('network') = {{item.0.netname}}
     with_subelements:
      - "{{ vlan }}"
      - netface
```

BR

Thx @Zeitounator

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. This should be integrated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make it easy

I want to create a file only if the server belongs to a particular network.

```
---
- name: Create file
  hosts: server
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    vlan:
      - netname: 192.168.3.0
        netface: "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
```

Tasks:

```
  tasks:
   - name: 
     file:
      path: /tmp/filetest
      state: touch
     when:
        (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item.0.netface]|default({}))
        .get('ipv4', {}).get('network') == item.0.netname
     loop:
     - "{{ vlan }}"
```

I have the network 192.168.3.0 but it doesn't create the file.

```
 ok: [server] => {
    "ansible_default_ipv4.network": "192.168.3.0"
}

 skipping: [server] => (item=[{u'netface': [u'lo', u'eth3', u'eth2', u'eth1', u'eth0'], u'netname': u'192.168.3.0'}])  => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": [
        {
            "netface": [
                "lo", 
                "eth3", 
                "eth2", 
                "eth1", 
                "eth0"
            ], 
            "netname": "192.168.3.0"
        }
    ], 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
```

I need a way to know how to compare the sensitive facts with a value in a variable.

Thanks

Comment: @Zeitounator, check this post. This is post that I commented